# Using PostgreSQL as package manager with R

Tags: r, database, postgresql, repository, rstudio

I am trying to use PostgreSQL as package manager with R but I am confused as in which method to use.

I tried connecting PostgreSQL directly with RStudio but could not use it as a package manager.
Also, I installed ubuntu and followed the posit package manager documentation where i installed RStudio package manager and posit package manager. It mentions using PostgreSQL as database.
Can anyone help clear my confusion with the correct method?

Comment: Using PostgreSQL as a package manager is very different than using PostgreSQL as a database. What exactly are you trying to do? I've never heard of using PostgreSQL as a package manager for R. Where did you learn about that? In R you might use a package like [RPostgres](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=RPostgres) to connect to database instance.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I used RPostgres to connect database instance from RStudio but then didn't know how to use that further as package manager.
I came across Posit package manager which uses SQLite and PostgreSQL as database while managing the packages, so thought this could be one way to do that.